# Laravel 5 Resource Controller Creation Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a resource controller by executing the following command

```
php artisan controller:make ImageController
```

but I'm having this error

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  There are no commands defined in the "controller" namespace.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It can be treated as a typo error .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Its a small mistake.

Change your code from:

```
php artisan controller:make ImageController
```

to

```
php artisan make:controller ImageController
```

Comment: the code created empty resource controller, <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    //
}

Comment: Do you want some boiler plate code also along with that?

Comment: I'm afraid that option is deprecated now. `php artisan make:controller  SampleController --plain` is the one used to create blank controller, but now it seems its creating blank controllers by default. But you can always create your own functions like `public function index() {  }`

Comment: This solution works but is this a change in documentation as there are posts which say "php artisan controller:make ImageController"

Comment: @isoCurator: Its a change from L5 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Just type the following command

```
php artisan make:controller Admin/MaterialController --resource
```

This Command generates the following resource controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MaterialController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```